# Copy iPhone photos retaining the creation time with windows

Tags: windows, iphone, copy

I would like to copy from explorer on Windows photos from an iPhone while retaining the creation time and date.

Which is the easiest way? I have to set it up for unexperienced users (robocopy on the command line is not really an option).

Comment: You specify that command line isn't an option for the audience - And I was trying to think of what could overcome this if the default Drag and Drop gets rid of the metadata, but have come short of anything as intuitive as Drag and Drop. Is a batch file that just needs to be double clicked acceptable for the audience?

Comment: Yes but the Directory on the iPhone is not always the same (source)

Comment: I notice that on both Apple and Microsoft's website their method to import pictures is the Import button from the Photos app, perhaps the Photos app has a method to store the metadata correctly?

Comment: Could be but it involves a lot of steps.

Comment: Does it mean that *Photos > Import > From a USB device* does not conserve the creation date? If so, could you please post one example photo that was obtained using the above method? I don't have an iPhone to test on.

Comment: I do not want to import all the pictures but just take some of them from explorer.

Comment: You can also select individual photos in *Photos*.

Comment: @Matteo when you look at the files from the USB connected iPhone in Windows Explorer, can you tell if the files at this level appear to have accurate date and time stamps? I vaguely recall iPhone mounted file systems with Windows either needing an app to read from the file system or perhaps the date and time stamps not looking correct from Windows File Explorer because of the different non-NTFS file system iPhone mounts with. Can you confirm that question though and maybe tell me if you can see what it says the file system type is mounted as when you do so. I might be able to help maybe.

Comment: Posting one example file will help us perhaps find a remedy to the problem.

Comment: The timestamps of the mounted iPhone are correct.

Comment: I know that I can export single pictures from the Photos app, but I don’t want to import all my pictures on the computer. I just have to take some of them by retaining the time stamp.

Comment: Have you tried copy/paste the photos using [TeraCopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy)?

Comment: @Matteo Would a PowerShell solution work that can be run by executing a batch script and the drive letter and path to images mounted e.g. `F:\DCIM\Photos` being the only thing the user needs to put into the prompt when prompted? I can potentially get a little fancier with it with a visual prompt to specify or pick from but curious to hear your feedback first. My son has an iPhone so I could test something but will wait to hear back first so just let me know. It'd be PowerShell that runs from a batch script by double clicking but maybe TeraCopy will work better for you, just let me know if so.

Comment: @Matteo: Photos does allow you to select what you import up to the single image. Again: A posted example image will help analyze the case, on OneDrive, Dropbox or any such online service.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you wanted to use the windows explorer, but as far as I know, it is quite complicated to do so, I tried it some years ago, and didn’t manage to do so. For my personal workflow I found two possible ways:

The [first](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/simple-transfer-pro-photos/id411292121) is a (paid) app that has a very nice user interface which can be accessed from a web browser. It shows all your albums and other infos, and when you download the photos as .zip-files, the time stamps are preserved.

The second is to just copy them with the windows explorer and then change the “edited” date and time to the time specified in the EXIF-metadata in the photo. This is by far not as user friendly as the first method, but it does not involve a paid app.

I hope this can help you, if you want me to go into more detail just ask but I didn’t want to write to much before I know if you are willing to thing about using other methods than the windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Photos app allows to select what to import, up to the single image,
with the correct date.

This function is available from the menu *Photos > Import > From a USB device*.

[image]

For images that were already imported with incorrect date, the correct date is
still available as meta-data embedded in the images. With the help of some
utilities (or scripts), this date can be transferred to the image-file on Windows.

If you wish us to take a look, post an example photo.

See the article
[How to Import Photos with Windows 10](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-import-photos-with-windows-10/?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPgcLpq7HtAhVFzRoKHTmiCfoQ9QF6BAgFEAI).

Comment: Not any more,  The "new" photos app has taken that away.  And the option in settings to download the legacy app it deleted, results in an error message "There has been an error".  If anyone has been able to download the legacy photos app please comment here!